# Is it time to review the low quality answers with notices on them?

Tags: discussion, answers

We have 18 [answers with notices](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasnotice%3ayes%20is%3aa) on them for being low-quality—the notice reads:

> **Want to improve this post?** Provide detailed answers to this question, including citations and an explanation of why your answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted.

Nearly all the notices are at least a year old, so there's been enough time for the authors of these answers to respond, if not the community. I think it is high time we review whether these answers have been improved satisfactorily and act on the post notices. (I had brought this up once before in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21415/conversation/suggestion-to-review-answers-with-notices) but it somehow dropped off the radar without any response.)

Here is the list of such answers (`(E)` means that it has been edited after the notice was added):

1. Score: 6. [Longest-running artist in music history?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7241/3955) (E). *[Invalidated LQP review](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/10003)*
2. Score: 3. [Nineties R&B song about a girl named Dinah (?)](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6825/3955) (E)
3. Score: 2. [Looking for a house album, with senior gentleman and snakeskin face on the cover](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6623/3955) (E)
4. Score: 2. [Slow R&B Jam, “Take my hand, we will live our life together”](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/8312/3955). *Accepted answer*
5. Score: 2. [Help identify a children's song about looking for a baby](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7164/3955). *Accepted answer*
6. Score: 2. [Instrumental 'chillwave' band from 2000s](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6380/3955) (E)
7. Score: 1. [Jazz ballad on “Getting Over It with Bennett Foddy - Speedrun” video](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6946/3955). *Accepted answer*
8. Score: 1. [Identify soundtrack for funny fast-motion runs or chases in comedy](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/8390/3955) (E)
9. Score: 1. [Haunting melody - famous song - slow quiet ballad](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6788/3955) (E)
10. Score: 1. [Identify traditional Scottish folk song about a kiss](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6469/3955) (E)
11. Score: 1. [1978 disco song with lyrics “Keep on, keep on, keep on dancing”](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6415/3955) (E)
12. Score: 1. [What's the song name in “Git Gud” video clip](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7077/3955) (E)
13. Score: 1. [Maniac | Official Trailer music](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6966/3955) (E)
14. Score: 0. [Old (Rock?) song sung by a guy. Instrumental sounds similar to Jerk It Out By Caesars but slower. Lyrics contain Woah oh oh oh oh](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7041/3955) (E)
15. Score: 0. [Identify soundtrack for the Roma teaser trailer?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7195/3955)
16. Score: 0. [Did Jimi Hendrix walk around stage during soundcheck to find feedback 'sweet spots'?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6667/3955)
17. Score: -1. [Was Mary a prostitute in Queensrÿche's “Operation: Mindcrime”?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/6983/3955) (E)
18. Score: -1. [Origin of “Who are you?” sample from DJ Shadow's “Circular Logic”](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/7063/3955)

There has been discussion in the past (see [here](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/285/3955) and [here](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/465/3955), for instance) about how to handle low-quality posts, and a consensus seems to be established in those discussions. We can use those discussions as a guide to act on these post notices.